# dask dataframe's read_csv can't read csv properly

Tags: dask

dask's read_csv() function can't read all the csv at a time properly but dask_cudf can.

da = dd.read_csv(os.path.join('data','*.csv'))

print(da.head())

[image]

Comment: Can you provide error message and input data in format which might be copy pasted?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @gbajson  there's no error message. dask just can't read file properly and having Nan values.


input data:

Timestamp, Bidprice, Askprice, Bidvolume, Askvolume
20040101 22:00:00:498,1.2542,1.25436,24.8999996185303,23.2000007629395,,,,
20040101 22:00:01:279,1.25417,1.25433,24.7000007629395,29.6000003814697,,,,
20040101 22:00:01:563,1.25414,1.2543,26.5,36.7000007629395,,,,
20040101 22:00:03:062,1.2542,1.25434,0.600000023841858,1.60000002384186,,,,